# How should I substitute an image in a larger animation using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

We're making a Flash browser game with a few reasonably complex animations. Our designer is making the animations in Flash Professional while I'm wiring everything up and adding some logic through AS3 (using FlashDevelop).

In one of our more complex animations a "bonus item" moves around the screen. It tweens hither and tither, there special effects and as such, it disappears for a few frames and then reappears later.

From AS3 we want to be able to dynamically decide which bonus item (say a mushroom or a star) to include in the animation. We don't want to have to ask our designer to replicate the entire animation for each of our bonus items.

**This is what we've tried:**

Created a two frame (1 mushroom frame, 1 star frame) "BonusItem" movieclip in FlashPro and Exported for ActionScript.
Created the complex animation movieclip in FlashPro and added the BonusItem movieclip to the relevant frames. Gave the BonusItem instance an instance name on all necessary KeyFrames. Exported entire movieclip for ActionScript (exported as "ComplexAnimation").

**Intention:**

The intention was to be able to do this:

```
var complexAnimation:ComplexAnimation = new ComplexAnimation();
complexAnimation.bonusItem.gotoAndStop("star"); // Frame labels have been added in FlashPRo.
this.addChild(complexAnimation);
```

This would play the complex animation with the star and we could easily call gotoAndStop("mushroom") to play the same animation with the mushroom.

**Problems:**

The first problem was that complexAnimation.bonusItem was null on line 02 above. I solved this by handling ADDED_TO_STAGE for complexAnimation and putting line 02 above in the handler.

The next problem was that each time the bonusItem movieclip started tweening, or if it was not present in some frames and was subsequently re-added the complexAnimation.bonusItem attribute/reference was reassigned to a new bonusItem instance. I then had to find a way to know when this was happening and call gotoAndStop("star") on the new instance.

I've found two ways to do this:

1) Listen for ADDED events on complexAnimation with a target.name of "bonusItem". It's a bit crap in a strongly typed language to have to resort to matching strings, but this works. Btw, when the ADDED event is fired new frame object references are still null.

2) Listen for FRAME_CREATED events. This happens later than ADDED at a point where new frame references have been initialized. As such I can check if complexAnimation.bonusItem is non-null at then call gotoAndStop("star") on it. One problem with this is that calling gotoAndStop actually triggers another FRAME_CREATED event to fire, so I need to guard against infinite looping. Again, it works but I don't have a great feeling about it.

**Conclusion:**

Well I don't really have a conclusion other than I feel like I'm working really hard to do something relatively simple. I'm hoping there's an easier & more robust approach. I have a strong feeling that I'm going crazy.  Anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an animation path that you want to be followed by some random image, right?

Comment: The image is not actually following an animation path (or motion guide). It does undergo a number of straight-line tweeens during the entire animation though.  I want to be able to programmatically specify in AS3 which image to use.

Comment: I made an error in the above post. Flash was indeed assigning a new instance of BonusItem, but it was caused by a Mask layer keyframe rather than the tween.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd update this post with our current (and hopefully long-term) solution.

First of all, I made an error in the above post:

> The next problem was that each time the bonusItem movieclip started tweening ... the complexAnimation.bonusItem attribute/reference was reassigned to a new bonusItem instance.

This was incorrect.  Flash was indeed assigning a new instance of BonusItem, but it was caused by a Mask layer keyframe rather than the tween.

I had been keen to try to avoid having any logic which relied on string comparisons, but in the end I swallowed my pride to make life easier.

Our designer gives all relevant objects (stuff that we'll need to access from AS3) instance names on each keyframe in the timeline.  If the object is nested within other objects our designer must assign those parent objects instance names too.  We must coordinate those instance names so that dev know what the accessors are called - we would've had to do all this anyway.  Our designer also still has to "Export For Actionscript" a class for each relevant movieclip (e.g. BonusItem).

In AS3 we're using [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org) for dependency injection and as the basis of our MVC framework.  Robotlegs suggests that application-specific logic should be separated from view-specific logic.  It allows us to specify a logic class (called a Mediator) to be associated with each and any of our views.  As such we can do the following mapping:

```
BonusItem -> BonusItemMediator
```

This means that every time Flash creates a BonusItem on the timeline Robotlegs somehow knows about it and creates a new instance of BonusItemMediator (which we write ourselves and have full control over).  In addition, Robotlegs can easily give us a reference from our BonusItemMediator to its associated view instance (the BonusItem instance).  So inside my BonusItemMediator I can ask the view reference what its instance name is.  I also walk up its parents to the stage and record each of their names to generate a resultant string of instance names that uniquely specified this instance of the BonusItem.
e.g.

```
"game.complexAnimation.bonusItem"
```

Once I know this I can ensure that the bonusItem is showing the correct image (star or mushroom) with the following code:

```
var frameLabelName:String myGameModel.whatTheHellShouldThisBeShowing("game.complexAnimation.bonusItem");
this.view.gotoAndStop(frameLabelName); // where view is the BonusItem instance
```

So now regardless of how or when Flash seemingly randomly decides to destroy and recreate my bonusItem I'll hear about it and can ensure that that new BonusItem instance is displaying on the correct frame.

The main weakness with this solution is that we're relying on string comparisons.  Our designer could easily mistype an instance name and we wouldn't hear about it until that code was hit at runtime.  Of course tests mitigate that risk, but I still feel that it's a shame that I'm using a strongly typed language, but then not making use of the compile time type checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object that exists on a timeline and it has an instance name, and you need to be able to maintain a reference to it through the duration of the timeline, then it *must* exist on every frame (and in the same layer!) of the movieclip.  I grant you, your workarounds get the job done but you have already experienced the pain involved in doing so.

The path of least resistance is to just have the object exist at all times.  If the user shouldn't "see" it, just hide it offscreen somewhere.  Just make sure it always exists, contiguously, on that timeline layer from frame 1 all the way to the final frame.

The other thing I'd suggest is to stop deeply nesting movieclips in the hopes of using those nested clips as state representations.  This is one of the things that sadly was very easy to do in the AS2 days, but has been rendered impractical to the point of madness in AS3.  Anything deeper than 1 layer is getting into some dicey territory.  3 layers deep and you need to rethink your strategy.  Perhaps instantiating different movieclip instances from the library and adding/removing dynamically instead of relying on frames.

Comment: Even if the object was to exist on all frames contiguously I'd still hit a problem.  Every time the object is tweened Flash is creating a new instance of BonusItem and assigning it to my complexAnimation.bonusItem reference.  As such I'd still have to resort to listening for events to tell each new instance of BonusItem to gotoAndStop on the relevant frame (star or mushroom).  Thanks for the input so far though.